# Trouble with grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, ubuntu-12.04

I am a first time user of node and grunt and npm and express and all that jazz, trying to get things setup and everything up to this point has been smooth. I have grunt installed globally. I try to run it in my project directory and I get the following error:

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

> grunt: symbol lookup error:
>   /home/tyler/foo/learningNode/new-proj/new-proj/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.22/binding.node:
>   undefined symbol:
>   _ZN4node12MakeCallbackEN2v86HandleINS0_6ObjectEEENS1_INS0_8FunctionEEEiPNS1_INS0_5ValueEEE

I've tried looking this up all over and can't even find the phrase "grunt: symbol lookup error:" anywhere. Seriously at a complete loss. If anyone has a clue it would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry, forgot to mention I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using node 0.11 the node-sass module doesn't work, not sure if that's the issue you're running into but there's an issue open on it [here https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/issues/229](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/issues/229)

Comment: thanks for the response, reading that other thread now to try and figure it out... sounds like I need to "downgrade" my version of node? I'll have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: On linux you can just rerun the steps that you used to install node the first time but with 0.10 instead of 0.11 and the binaries will be replaced. If you plan on trying out 0.11 maybe give nvm a try. I use it on my development machines to try out different versions of node.